# a total sum of 2 textviews

Tags: android

```
private int ScoreCount;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.score);
    
    final TextView TotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);
    final TextView One = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score1);
    
    One.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ScoreCount++;
            Front9.setText("" + ScoreCount);
        }
    });
```

If i fill a random number in both textviews, i want a sum of the 2 numbers in the totalscore.
how do i do that. is the code i added the right way to do this.
i know that the onclicklistener is not the right way but what to use instead.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a TextWatcher http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Assuming you have code to take care of incrementing each of your score TextViews, hook up each of the TextViews with a TextWatcher like so

```
One.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int score1 = Integer.parseInt(One.getText());
        int score2 = Integer.parseInt(Two.getText());
        FrontNine.setText(String.valueOf(score1 + score2));
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

**Edit** - Apparently I misunderstood the question. To increment each of the scores, using a click handler is an acceptable approach. See code above for the complete example. Disregard the comments and code above.

```
private int scoreTotal1;
private int scoreTotal2;
private int overallTotalScore;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.score);

    scoreTotal1 = 0;
    scoreTotal2 = 0;
    overallTotalScore = 0;

    final TextView textViewtotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalScore);
    final TextView textViewOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score1);
    final TextView textViewTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score2);

    textViewOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scoreTotal1++;
            overallTotalScore = scoreTotal1 + scoreTotal2;
            textViewOne.setText(String.valueOf(scoreTotal1));
            textViewTotalScore.setText(String.valueOf(overallTotalScore));
        }
    });

    textViewTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scoreTotal2++;
            overallTotalScore = scoreTotal1 + scoreTotal2;
            textViewTwo.setText(String.valueOf(scoreTotal2));
            textViewTotalScore.setText(String.valueOf(overallTotalScore));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how to do incrementing each of the score TextViews?