# Total value of multiple textviews into a single textiew?

Tags: android, string, onclick, textview, int

I used the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282661/a-total-sum-of-2-textviews) to get the basic value of the TextView clicks into a single TextView .This code gives a per click value, I want to know how to add the existing value of TextView. 
Note: m1aa and m1ab are number variables in a previous activity and received through intent on this one.

*UPDATE* This question should have been "how do you convert a string to a decimal."

```
    //Original non working code.
    private int productTotal1;
    private int productTotal2;
    private int overallTotalproduct;


    private TextView m1a, 
    private TextView m1aa, 

    //and then way down the page

    productTotal1 = 0;
    productTotal2 = 0;
    overallTotalproduct = 0;

    final TextView textViewtotalproduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1aa);
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1ab);

    textView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            productTotal1++;
            overallTotalproduct = productTotal1 + productTotal2;
            textView1.setText(String.valueOf(productTotal1));
            textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(overallTotalproduct));
        }
    });

    textView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            productTotal2++;
            overallTotalproduct = productTotal1 + productTotal2;
            textView2.setText(String.valueOf(productTotal2));
            textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(overallTotalproduct));
        }
    });
```

***UPDATE***WORKS FINE :)
 AFTER GETTING HELP AND "THINKING" ABOUT WHAT I WAS WRITING I END UP WITH...

```
//Working version
private double overallTotalproduct;



    final TextView textViewtotalproduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1aa);
    final String stringm1aa = textView1.getText().toString();
    final double intm1aa = Double.parseDouble(stringm1aa);


    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1ab);
    final String stringm1ab = textView2.getText().toString();
    final double intm1ab = Double.parseDouble(stringm1ab);
```

Comment: what do you actually want?

Comment: I want to know how to add the existing value of TextView not 0. m1aa and m1ab are number variables in a previous activity and received through intent on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to get a value of `TextView` and convert it to integer

```
String s = textView.getText().toString();
int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Remember `NumberFormatException` will be thrown if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Comment: I was able to get this working like this. I didn't know how to convert a text value to an integer so thank you. Here it is. I don't understand it all. Feel like there is some useless code in there but it works.

Comment: Pleasae dont use without understanding.. see the java Integer class. Integer.parsInt convert an string to integer

Comment: Thank You...I'm still very new at this. I meant "I" had some useless code but I am learning.